# chmod does not change permissions of certain directories

Tags: permissions, ext4, chmod

System file: `ext4`

I changed the owner of files to `apache:` with the command:

```
chown -R apache: wp.localhost
```

Then, I could not change the permissions of directories in wp.localhost nor the wp.localhost itself

I use the command `chmod +w wp.localhost` for example. and I do not see any permission change on it.

I also changed the group of folders by the command again, But did not solve the problem.

```
chown -R apache:users wp.localhost
```

**Commads and permissions before and after:**

```
#ls -ld wp.localhost
drwxr-xr-x 6 apache users 4096 Mar 28 15:26 wp.localhost/
# chmod +w wp.localhost
# ls -ld wp.localhost
drwxr-xr-x 6 apache users 4096 Mar 28 15:26 wp.localhost/
```

Comment: Can you include the output of `ls -ld wp.localhost` before and after the commands you say don't work?

Comment: @Flup: sure, added to question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to grant global write permission on that directory, you have to do

```
chmod a+w wp.localhost [1]
```

This is because omitting the 'who is affected' letter (`u`, `g`, `o` or `a`) implies `a`, but won't set bits that are set in your current `umask`.  So, for example, if your `umask` was `0022`, the 'write' bit is set in the 'group' and 'other' positions, and `chmod` will ignore it if you don't specify `a` explicitly.

The `chmod` man page is explicit about this:

> If none of these ['who is affected' letters] are given, the effect is
>   as if `a` were given, but bits that are set in the umask are not
>   affected.

[1] Think carefully before doing this!

Comment: You are right, I used `chmod g+w wp.localhost` and worked correctly, Thanks

Comment: But I have a question. On normal conditions the letter of 'who is affected' does not needed for giving permission to all. Why now became necessary?

Comment: Impossible to say what's changed.  Perhaps your `umask` has changed.